# SWI-Prolog parsing DCG predicate doesn't work

Tags: parsing, prolog

I have a predicate with the goal of parsing a grammar. 
The productions of the grammar are:

`S-> B 
 B->bB
 B->b`

The predicate is intended to take in a list and determine whether or not the list belongs to the grammar. My code is as follows:

```
s(List,[]):- b(List,[]).
b(List,[]):-'C'(List,b,X), b(X,[]).
b([b|List],List).
```

The predicate seems to be able to determine that [b] is a solution, however, it is unable to detect that [b,b,b] is also a solution.

For instance,

```
?-s([b],[]).
 true.
?-s([b,b,b],[]).
 false.
```

I think the second line of my code isn't doing what I want it to, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Use a [tag:dcg] instead! `s --> b. b --> [b], b. b --> [b].` usage: `phrase(b, L).`

Comment: Wow, I was dramatically over complicating this. Thanks!

Comment: Even simpler: `b --> [b], ( [] | b ).`

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to understand the basics of Prolog and DCGs, see this solution:

```
s(List):- b(List,[]).
b([b|List],Rest):- b(List,Rest).
b([b],[]).
```